# Oracle SQL In Subquery taking too much time as compared to hard coded values

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, query-optimization

I have a simple query that is taking approx 2 minutes to run as compared to 8 seconds when executed with a hard coded value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = (SELECT PREV_WORKING_DAY 
                          FROM TABLE_B )
```

`SELECT PREV_WORKING_DAY FROM TABLE_B` returns '20-JUN-2019'.

Both TRANSACTION_DATE & PREV_WORKING_DAY are of Date format.

When we hardcode date in the query output is 100 milli seconds

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = '20-JUN-2019'
```

Total records = 82,000

Any idea what is causing the latency when using a subquery and how can we optimise same.

I know I can convert same in PL/SQL and assign the value to a variable but still I want to understand what is causing the latency.
thanks

Comment: Table B has a single row? Or is there some correlation between the two tables that you haven't shown? (Also '20-JUN-2019' is not a date, it's a string, so there is implicit conversion going on). You might want to include the execution plans for both queries.

Comment: Do you have an index over TABLE_A? Explain both queries to see if first query is not using the index.

Comment: How does 'SELECT PREV_WORKING_DAY FROM TABLE_B' return just a single row? Is there only one row in the table?

Comment: Yes, The table_B has only one record for PREV_WORKING_DAY.

Comment: @AlexPoole The only relation between Table_A & Table_B is TRANSACTION_DATE. Basically Table_A keeps a list of all my transactions and Table_B keeps a records of My Previous_working_day, Today and next working day.

Comment: Do you update table B every day, or delete and reinsert that single row - possibly many times (or insert then delete)? Just wondering if it's doing a full table scan of B and it has a too-high high water mark; though that doesn't sound quite right, and 2 minutes still sounds too long. If gathering stats doesn't help, how about truncating the table and recreating the row? Again, look at - or include - the execution plans to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you have no or very stale statistics for TABLE_B, so Oracle doesn't know it's only got one row. Consequently it chooses an inefficient plan. 
The Explain Plan will tell you the cardinality of the subquery.

If that is it the solution is:

```
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TABLE_B');
```

You should read [the documentation on gathering statistics](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm).

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you switch to a `JOIN`?

```
SELECT A.*
FROM TABLE_A A JOIN
     TABLE_B B
     ON A.TRANSACTION_DATE B.PREV_WORKING_DAY;
```

Comment: Can you provide execution plans for the two queries